# SnpEff gene annotation with @ such as PCDHB@

Tags: vcf, sequence-annotation, variant-calling, functional-annotation

I'm using snpEff to annotate some VCFs and getting some spurious annotations that don't have transcript ids. Some of these annotations have a gene name followed by ampersand such as PCDHB@ and I'm not finding any explanation in the docs.

Any idea what this refers to? Entire gene family?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` at the end of a name denotes a "gene cluster in chromosome region". This is mentioned in the official [HUGO nomenclature guidelines](https://www.genenames.org/about/guidelines/) in the "Characters reserved for specific usage" section:

[image: [HUGO reserved characters table]

It's also mentioned in the [GeneCards documentation](https://www.genecards.org/Guide/GeneCard):

[image]

Comment: Very informative. Thanks!